# In wiki page how to create a table with rows having autonumbering

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I am looking for wiki table with row having auto numbering feature. If it is not a table, using # will generate the autonumbering.

Currently the numbers are hardcoded as below

```
{| border="1"
|-
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | S.No 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Project 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | File 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Modified By 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Modified Date 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Changes Made 
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Reviewed By
! style="background: #aaaaaa" | Comments
|-
| 1 
| /abcd
| 
| 
| 
| 
| 
| needs merge
|-
| 2 
| /abcd
| 
| 
| 
| 
| 
| needs merge
|-
| 3 
| /abcd 
| 
| 
| 
| 
| needs merge
|}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Extension:Autoincrement](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Autoincrement)

Then simply add `{{AUTOINCREMENT}}` where the numbers should be.

Each time the `{{AUTOINCREMENT}}` hook is used on a page it will return a number increased by one from the last use.

Keep in mind that if you have two tables on the same page, the second table will start from where previous table numbering stopped + 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters), or Javascript.